# Did I correctly perform extract max operation on this max-heap?

Tags: data-structures, heap

I am trying to understand how heaps work.

I have the following heap:

[image]

Now I want to extract the max value.

The first thing I do is delete the root 42, then put the last element in the heap (6) at the root position. I then perform max-heapify to find the correct spot for 6.

6 i larger than its two children, so I swap it with the largest child 41, making 41 the new root.

6 now has the children 3 and 9, I therefore again swap it with the larger child 9

In the end I end up with the heap

[image]

Did I correctly perform extract-max?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!
Extract max works recursively.find the largest element among the three i.e parent and two of their children.If largest is not parent swap largest element to parent and call extract max to largest.